# My page is broken, I don't know why their is a horizontal scroll when there should be none

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css

This is my first bootstrap design and I think I am doing pretty well but my friend just pointed out that I have a horizontal scroll in browser. Where is this happening and why is it happening? *Horizontal Scroll -> Scroll bar left to right in the browser. If you want to check out the site directly here is the link: https://affattraction.com

> HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>AffAttraction | Performance Based Marketing Network</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.mini.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
</head>
<body>
<!-- Header -->
    <header>
        <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>
                    <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">AffAttraction</a>
                </div>
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="advertisers.html">Advertisers</a></li>
                    <li><a href="publishers.html">Publishers</a></li>
                    <li><a href="blog.html">Blog</a></li>
                    <li><a href="about.html">About Us</a></li>
                    <li><a href="contact.html">Contact Us</a></li>
                </ul>
                <form class="navbar-form navbar-right">
                <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email" required="">
                <input type="password" name="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" required="">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-green">Login <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span></button>
                </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </header>
<!-- Header -- >
<!-- Showcase -->
    <div id="showcase">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-12">
                <h1><span class="highlight">Performance</span> Based Marketing</h1>
                <p>Do you have traffic? Do you want to monetize it? AffAttraction can help you earn more from your websites, apps, games, blogs, and more!</p>

                <center><a href="advertisers.html"><button class="btn btn-showcase">Advertisers</button></a>
                <a href="publishers.html"><button class="btn btn-showcase">Publishers</button></a></center>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
<!-- Showcase -->
<!-- Overview -->
    <div id="overview">
        <div class="contianer">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-6">
                    <h1>What is AffAttraction?</h1>
                    <p>AffAttraction is a CPA (Cost-Per-Action) Affiliate Network consisting of the top converting and highest paying ad campaigns around the globe. We offer a easy-to-use custom tracking platform with advanced tracking, advanced tools, and top support.</p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-6">
                    <h1>Why Choose AffAttraction?</h1>
                    <p>We strive to provide the latest tools and features for our advertisers and publishers to bring you the best experience in CPA Marketing. We also offer the top converting and highest paying ad campaigns around the globe.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
<!-- Overview -->
<!-- Features -->
    <div id="features">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-6">
                    <h1>•Customizable Payouts</h1>
                    <p>Every affiliate has customizable payouts depending on your revenue stream. If your traffic is good and you exceed the minimum amount for that month/week, contact us and we can re-schedule your payment dates.</p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-6">
                    <h1>•Detailed Reports and Statistics</h1>
                    <p>Our custom tracking platform although very easy-to-use is very complex and tracks every detail of a click. Generate reports in real-time in the reports seciton of your publisher panel.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-6">
                    <h1>•Highest Conversion Rates</h1>
                    <p>We don't waste our time adding offers that do not convert. Every offer on our network has been hand tested to make sure it converts correctly. Higher conversion rates means more revenue oppourtunities!
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-6">
                    <h1>•Daily Support</h1>
                    <p>Our Dedicated Affiliate Managers are here 7 days a week to help you through any encounters you may have while working with AffAttraction!</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-6">
                    <h1>•Exclusive Tools</h1>
                    <p>Postback and API are a some of the tools you will be able to use while working with AffAttraction. Don't forget, we will be adding more in the future!</p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-6">
                    <h1>•User Privacy</h1>
                    <p>Don't worry, we will never share your information with 3rd Parties. Your personal information is secure when entering anything our our domain. User protection is high priority with AffAttraction!</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-12">
                    <a href="publishers/register.php"><button class="btn btn-get-started">Get Started</button></a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
<!-- Features -->
<!-- Footer -->
    <div class="footer-header">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-4">
                        <h1>About Us</h1>
                        <p>AffAttraction is a Performance Based Marketing Network helping publishers earn more from thier traffic by offering advanced tracking, exclusive tools, top support and the highest paying ad campaigns around the globe.</p><br>

                        <p><b>Join our Network <br>and Start Earning from your Traffic!</b></p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-4">
                        <h1>Network</h1>
                        <p><a href="blog.html">->Blog</a></p>
                        <p><a href="publishers/login.php">->Login</a></p>
                        <p><a href="terms.html">->Terms of Service</a></p>
                        <p><a href="privacy.html">->Privacy Policy</a></p>
                        <p><a href="contact.html">->Contact Us</a></p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-4">
                        <h1>AffAttraction</h1>
                        <p>RR1 Box 3010 Rock Branch Road<br>
                        Poca, WV 25159 - United States</p><br>

                        <a href="contact.html">Contact Us:</a>
                        <a href="mailto:affiliate@affattraction.com">affiliate@affattraction.com</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    <footer>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-12">
                <p>&copy; 2017 AffAttraction. All Rights Reserved.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </footer>
<!-- footer -->
<script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.mini.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.mini.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

> CSS

```
body {
    font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif;
    background-color: #F4F4F4;
}

/* Global */
.btn-green {
    background-color: #00FF00;
    border: none;
}

.btn-green:hover {
    background-color: #32CD32;
    border: none;
}

.highlight {
    color: #32CD32;
}

.btn-showcase {
    height: 50px;
    width: 140px;
    margin: 10px;
    background-color: #00FF00;
    border: none;
    font-size: 16px;
    color: black;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

.btn-showcase:hover {
    height: 50px;
    width: 140px;
    margin: 10px;
    background-color: #32CD32;
    border: none;
    font-size: 16px;
    color: black;
}

.btn-get-started {
    height: 50px;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 10px;
    background-color: white;
    border: black 3px solid;
    border-radius: 0;
    font-size: 16px;
    color: black;
    transition: all 0.5s linear;
}

.btn-get-started:hover {
    height: 50px;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 10px;
    background-color: black;
    border: white 3px solid;
    border-radius: 0;
    font-size: 16px;
    color: white;
}

/* Header */
.navbar-default {
    background-color: #418DD9;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 0px;
    min-height: 60px;
}

.navbar a {
    color: white !important;
    border-top: #418DD9 3px solid;
}

.navbar-nav a:hover {
    color: white !important;
    border-top: #00FF00 3px solid;
}

.navbar-brand {
    font-size: 25px !important;
}

.navbar-form {
    padding-top: 5px;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-toggle .icon-bar {
    background-color: white !important;
}

/* Showcase */
#showcase {
    margin-top: -20px;
    min-height: 400px;
    color: #FFFFFF !important;
    background: url('../img/showcase.jpg') fixed;
    border: none;
    position: relative;
}

#showcase h1 {
    font-size: 60px;
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 40px;
}

#showcase p {
    font-size: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 15px;
}

/* Overview */
#overview {
    padding: 10px;
    background-color: #DCDCDC;
}
#overview h1 {
    font-size: 35px;
    text-align: center;
    color: black;
}

#overview p {
    font-size: 16px;
    text-align: center;
    color: black;
}

/* Footer Bottom */
footer {
    background-color: #4169E1;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    min-height: 60px;
}

footer p {
    font-size: 15px;
    padding-top: 20px;
}

.footer-header {
    background-color: #418DD9;
    color: #FFFFFF;
}

.footer-header h1 {
    font-size: 20px;
}

.footer-header a {
    color: #FFFFFF;
    text-decoration: none;
    transition: all 0.3s linear;
}

.footer-header a:hover {
    color: #00FF00;
}

/* Features */

#features {
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
}

#features h1 {
    font-size: 25px;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

Also, I am using bootstrap (latest version) so it could be something in their files but I wouldn't think so. I didn't notice this so I don't know where it started.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You misspelled "container" after the `<div id="overview">`

Comment: This fixed it! Thanks :D

Answer (score 0):

there is problem in `#overview` element, if you delete the `row` under `container`, you will see its going to be fixed.